# Using an inner class to create a private record for the outer class in java / inner methods visibility

Tags: java, visibility, inner-classes

I have to implement an interface called `Graph<E>` in Java.

Let's say `MyGraph<E extends Comparable<E>>` is the class I'm writing to implement Graph.

I would like to create an inner class `Node` in order to "encapsulate" the elements of Type `E`.

```
public class MyGraph<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Graph<E>{


  MyGraph methods and instance variables...
  .
  .
  .



    class Node {
        E elem;
        List<E> edges;
        ...
        public Node(E e){
           this.elem = e;
           edges = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I can't understand if the inner class should be `Node` or `Node<E>`, `public` or `private` and if the instance variables of it should be declared `public` or `private` . And the same for some eventual methods I'm going to insert in `Node`.

Basically the class Node should be like a record type in C (with `typedef`), and the outer class should be able to access all the instance variable of Node **without observers**, **getters, etc.**

Comment: Your `Node` should be a `private` class, because it's a part of the `MyGraph` definition and shouldn't be accessible and modifiable by the outside classes. You're performing some calculations on your nodes, that are the part of your Graph. You don't need to make it parameterized  as it's already of a parameterized class (i.e `MyGraph <E...>`).
Have a look at this excellent resource from Princeton on Algorithms in Java http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/

Comment: You should declare the Node class `private static` as it doesn't need access to the members of the outer class. If you don't do this every instance will carry a reference to the instantiating instance. You will need to give it a parameter to do this. If you use _E_ as the parameter name it will shadow the _E_ in the outer class, so consider giving it a different name for clarity. Your outer class will have full access to the members of `Node`, and no other class will have access if `Node` is private, so you don't need to worry about the access level of the members—just omit them.

Comment: @teppic Can you explain me what does it mean "If you don't do this every instance will carry a reference to the instantiating instance" ?

Comment: @GerardoZinno: inner classes have access to the methods and fields of the enclosing instance. To accomplish this every instance of an inner class has an implicit reference to its parent instance, `MyGraph.this` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the Node class private static as it doesn't need access to the members of the outer class. If you don't do this every instance will carry a reference to the instantiating instance. You will need to give it a parameter to do this.

If you use E as the parameter name it will shadow the E in the outer class, so consider giving it a different name for clarity. Your outer class will have full access to the members of Node, and no other class will have access if Node is private, so you don't need to worry about the access level of the members—just omit them.